# FOR loop to print out numbers in sequence and equal distance?

Tags: c++, for-loop

A local lottery game has 49 numbers (1 to 49 inclusive). Players must choose 6 numbers. You wish to choose 6 numbers where each number is as far apart from the number below it as the number above it, i.e. there is an equal distance between the numbers, and it is the maximum distance possible.
Write a for statement that prints the sequence of 6 numbers using the smallest amount of code possible.

I tried to code the loop so that there are equal distances between each number enetered but it doesnt not seem to work.

Any advice on how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
 

/* function main begins program execution */
int main(void)
{
    int lotteryNumberSelection;
    int lotteryNumberSum = 0;


    std::cout << "Please enter 6 numbers between 1 and 49";
    std::cin >> lotteryNumberSelection;

    if (lotteryNumberSelection <= 49)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter 6 numbers between 1 and 49";

    }
    else
    {

        for (int lotteryNumberCounter = 1; lotteryNumberCounter <= 6; lotteryNumberCounter += lotteryNumberSelection++) {

            lotteryNumberSum += lotteryNumberSelection;

            std::cout << "Your lucky numbers are" << lotteryNumberSum << std::endl;


        }
         /* indicate program ended successfully */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"each number is as far apart from the number below it as the number above it"_ implies that you simply find the total number of values (49 - 1 + 1), divide by the number of values that fit in that range (6 - 1) and truncate (automatic for integers). So you have 49 possible values. `49 / 5` is equal to 9, which is the maximum distance possible between numbers. There are four possible sequences with starting values from 1 to 4 (_i.e._ 49 - 5 * 9). Choose one.

Comment: Hi paddy and thanks for your comment, looking back, would it not be 49/6? so 8? becouse 1-6 including 1 and 6?

Comment: No. If you put your left hand at one end of your desk, and your right hand at the other end of your desk (fitting two hands with maximum distance between them on your desk), do you divide the desk width by 2? No, you divide it by _one less_ because there is always one fewer _gap_ between items than the number of items.

Comment: What does"it doesnt not seem to work" mean?

Comment: I mean it does not display the "the sequence of 6 numbers ". Any advice on how i can make my code better so that it does?

Comment: @paddy i got the for loop to work but still not sure how to code the maximum distance allowed part, any advice? I am just a begineer in C and struggling with some concepts

Comment: This is my code right now: void main(void)

{

 int luckynumcount;

 // lucky numbers

 for (luckynumcount = 1; luckynumcount <= 49; luckynumcount++)

  printf("%d ", luckynumcount);

 printf("\n");

}

Comment: That loop outputs 49 numbers. I thought you wanted 6. You need to use math to work out how much to add each time around the loop. I even hinted at the formulae for calculating this in my very first comment. It's up to you to figure out how to generalize that using variables instead of constant values. Then you will be able to make your program work with any range of numbers.